# Repeat random array pick once code is run

Tags: javascript

This picks a number out of an array when the code is run. How do I make it pick a new number every ten seconds?

```
var myArray = [49,50,51,52,53];
var randomNumber = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
```

Comment: you can use setInterval and call the expression in each 10 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) in order to execute some code every `x` milliseconds. In the below example this happens every 2 seconds. Change `2000` for `10000` and you'll get the desired result.

```js
var myArray = [49, 50, 51, 52, 53];

setInterval(function() {
  var randomNumber = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

  console.log(randomNumber)
}, 2000); //replace 2000 for 10000
```

---

The previous code doesn't take into account whether a number was selected or not previously in order to pick a new one. If you want to select a new number every time until there are no more numbers, you can do it like this:

```js
var myArray = [49, 50, 51, 52, 53];

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (!myArray.length) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  } else {
    var randomNumber = myArray.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length), 1)[0];

    console.log(randomNumber)
  }
}, 2000); //replace 2000 for 10000
```

Comment: Thank you, the first piece of code worked perfectly for what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.setInterval(function, ms)` to execute code in intervals.

```js
var myArray = [49,50,51,52,53];
var randomNumber = getRandomArrayMember(myArray);
console.log(randomNumber);

function getRandomArrayMember(arr) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) return arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
}

setInterval(
  function() { 
    randomNumber = getRandomArrayMember(myArray); 
    console.log(randomNumber) 
  }, 10000);
```